# Mongoose - validate if schema paths matches properties provided

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm trying to achieve the same behaviour as you may experience using e.g. MySQL

> Unknown column '...' in 'field list'

I have 2 files

**1 - models/user.js**

```
// ...
let user = new mongoose.Schema({
    forename: String,
    surname: String
});

user.pre('save', (next)=> {
    // can I do the validation here ?
    next();
});
// ...
```

2 - **seeder.js**

```
// ...
let user = require('./models/user');

let usr = new user({name: "some forename", surname: "some surname"});

usr.save((error, response)=>{
    // ...
});
// ...
```

What I want to do is to throw an error that the `name` property is not in the schema paths.

Any ideas ? Or should I create a custom class which extends `mongoose.Schema` with custom methods for this kind of validation ?

Answer (score 0):

Mongoose validation runs when the pre-save middleware runs, so that's probably a good place to put your validation code. See the [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#schematype_SchemaType-validate) on validation.

Comment: Note also that if you simply want to avoid saving data that isn't a valid schema path, those are ignored by default. If you want the error, though you'll have to implement that as you're trying to do.